# Side-loading objects with non-standard class names in EmberJS with Rails+active_model_serializers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I have a few models in Rails that look something like this:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reporter, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :comments
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

with serializers like so:

```
class IssueSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  embed :ids, include: true

  has_one :reporter, :embed => :ids
  has_one :assignee, :embed => :ids
end

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end

class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :body
end
```

This produces JSON that looks something like the following:

```
{
  "issues": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "reporter_id": 1,
      "assignee_id": 2,
      "comment_ids": [
        3
      ]
    },
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 3
      "body": "Great comment"
    }
  ],
  "reporters": [
    {
      "id": 1
      "name": "Ben Burton"
    }
  ],
  "assignees": [
    {
      "id": 2
      "name": "Jono Mallanyk"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is that the side-loaded reporters and assignees JSON objects aren't recognized by Ember as User objects, and I see the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key reporters but you have no mapping for it
```

I don't want to remove

```
embed :ids, include: true
```

from my IssueSerializer, because then the comments wouldn't be serialized.

There are a few potential ways to solve this that I've considered:

- If the embed method for ActiveModel::Serializer accepted a list of models in its include option, this could filter the JSON response to only include side-loaded comments.
- Ember data's model could be configured to side load users from "users", "reporters" and "assignees"... but as far as I can tell from the source it only appears to support one key for sideloadAs.
- Somehow ignore/disable side-loading errors for unknown keys (probably the least sane approach).

Is there another option I'm missing here? I think I may have to write a fix and submit a pull request to either rails-api/active_model_serializers, emberjs/data, or both.

**EDIT**: My temporary workaround for this is to change the IssueSerializer to only serialize the ids for reporter and assignee:

```
class IssueSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :reporter_id, :assignee_id
  embed :ids, include: true

  has_many :comments, :embed => :ids
end
```

Comment: Could you show your Issue Model?

Comment: Your response below got it right.

Comment: What version of Ember-data are you using?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem and have found solution at [ActiveModel::Serializers readme](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#embedding-associations). You can use `:root` option. Try something like this for issue serializer:

```
class IssueSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id
  embed :ids, include: true

  has_one :reporter, :root => "users"
  has_one :assignee, :root => "users"
  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment: This wipes the previous side loaded objects so if there are some user reporters that aren't assignees then it won't work. Still it is useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

You should read [this](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#revision-12) page. The section of Revision 12 explains about the sideloading of data of the same type:

> Now, homeAddress and workAddress will be expected to be sideloaded
>   together as addresses because they are the same type. Furthermore, the
>   default root naming conventions (underscore and lowercase) will now
>   also be applied to sideloaded root names.

Your Model should be like:

```
App.Issue  = DS.Model.extend({
  reporter: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
  assignee: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});
```

The JSON Result should have a key for the users:

```
{
  "issues": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "reporter_id": 1,
      "assignee_id": 2,
      "comment_ids": [
        3
      ]
    },
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 3
      "body": "Great comment"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1
      "name": "Ben Burton"
    },{
      "id": 2
      "name": "Jono Mallanyk"
    }
  ]
}
```

Because you configured in your Model that the `reporter` is of type `User`, Ember search for a user in the result.

Comment: The convention that Ember expects "users" as the side-loaded collection of user models is inconsistent with the active_model_serializers convention that the objects are embedded at the top level with the field name. It would be great if it would side-load User objects under "users," but it does not.

Comment: The convention for active_model_serializers is still on the [roadmap](https://github.com/emberjs/data#roadmap). Do you still have the problem with another exception?

Comment: The solution I have at the moment is simply not to side-load the Users at all by only serializing the ids in the Issue (see my edit above). This isn't great, obviously, because a second request is needed if the User models aren't in the store. After thinking about this for a little while, I think that what Ember does is perfectly reasonable. I think that active_model_serializers has a (maybe?) bug in that it's serializing the models based on the alias and not the class name.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, adding `include: false` on the association did the trick for me.

```
    embed :ids, include: true
    attributes :id, :title

    has_many :domains, key: :domains, include: false
    has_many :sessions, key: :sessions
```