# What are side loaded objects?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have read a [few threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363333/side-loading-objects-with-non-standard-class-names-in-emberjs-with-railsactive) [where they mention side loaded objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027412/ember-data-accessing-a-list-of-sideloaded-resources). I can't find a clear deffinition on what they are though. What are side loaded objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**These are associated objects loaded in the same request as the main one.**

Much like ActiveRecord's eager loading with `includes` that fetches not only specified objects, but also objects associated with them in a few queries, instead of fetching for each object separately, making N+1 queries. ActiveRecord reduces the number of DB queries with this technique, Ember.js reduces the number of HTTP requests, and **differently**: in *simplest* case of one association you'd make **two** queries, but **with sideloading** you only have to make **one**.

[See Ember.js docs.](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/)

*Disclaimer: it's just a conclusion I've made from the docs, I've never worked with Ember.*